# Screen Orientation by user choice

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-manifest, screen-orientation

I have an app where the user is asked whether they'll run the app in Portrait or Landscape mode on the login screen. Once they choose I want the entire app to be in the desired orientation.

I tried multiple way to do it but it always ends up conflicting with other aspects of the app. For instance, I tried to save the user choice in SharedPreference (which is great) and get the value onCreate in every activity. It worked but it causes my main view to be created twice in a row which causes issues in other non related areas of the app.

Is there a way to inject my screen orientation from the login screen to the Manifest or as a global variable to the app?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

But you have to make your ui as per screen mode otherwise user will get bad ui experience

Comment: Thats exactly what i'm doing at the moment. But when I restart the activity (I send a command from my backend to refresh the activity) the screen initially runs in portrait mode (for less than 1 second) then immediately changes to landscape. This 1 delay is causing issues for me. I was looking for someway to change the entire app orientation right from the log in screen.

Comment: i dont know but have you ever seen a application that has same feature ?

Comment: if yes then there would be a solution otherwise no chance

Comment: Honestly.. no I haven't seen anything like that. I'm doing an app for an Android TV box and it has no sensor for orientation so I have to deal with it manually. Maybe I just make 2 version of the app one in portrait and one in landscape.

Comment: i think you can do it but you have to learn about dynamic modules

Comment: Go through android documentation and learn about dynamic feature module it will help you

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out.

Comment: what problems are you seeing? the activity is always recreated when orientation is changed. maybe you can persist those initial data when the activity is just created for the first time.